# Antivirus software detecting my C# application as Gen.Variant.Zusy

Tags: c#, .net, client-server, antivirus

I've built a server-client application in C# .NET and it is a normal irc chat client. Using Tcp Listener on the server side and opened a socket to handle client connection. When I debug or launch the "server" software, my Bitdefender detects it as a Gen.Variant.Zusy.166707 virus. I researched a bit and it said these viruses open up sockets to allow attackers to harm your computer but my server software isn't made for harming. Any way I can get rid of such problems or some way to make the server software safely run on any computer as I will be using this server software for my next game and if it keeps triggering antivirus software, it'll be suspicious and will be never used.

Comment: Did you used a port the `Gen.Variant.Zusy.166707 virus` used?

Comment: If there was a way to mark an application *not to be detected* by an antivir-software, wouldn´t all hackers around the world immediateley mark their viruses as such? You can´t say an antivir-app that your app is safe, this is what the antivir should check itself, isn´t it?

Comment: Well I used the port 1441. Don't really know if that's a port used by the Gen.Variant.Zusy

Answer (score 0):

Well if your antivirus can detect it as a virus, others will as well. In this case you'll have to recreate your server unfortunately.

Comment: Exactly how? What code should I differ to get out of this problem?